# Two floated divs with a flexible div in-between

Tags: css, layout, html, css-float

I need the following in a header of fixed width:

1. A div of varying width floated left.
2. A div of varying width floated right.
3. An h2 centered between them that takes up any remaining space.

The floated divs contain content that may vary in size.

I've tried various approaches but they have all failed. I know one solution is to absolutely position the outer divs, then stretch the h2 out for the full width and center the text so it sits centrally, but there must be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: It would be nice to see what you tried so we don't duplicate our efforts.

Comment: Floated containers should (ideally) be given a width. I think that would solve your problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A basic **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EqabH/)** with minimal markup.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
    <h2>H2</h2>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    border:1px solid #999;
}
#left {
    float:left;
}
#right {
    float:right;
}
h2 {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
}
```

​

Comment: The OP says the #left and #right containers have varying content, so I imagine a `width` would be required to prevent them taking up the full width, but otherwise this would be my suggestion as well, +1

Comment: @w3d - actually no. Floating them effectively shrinks them to fit the content automatically.

Comment: That is fine if the content is relatively small, but if the content goes beyond a certain size it will begin to take the full width (and then some).

Comment: This is really nice. Thanks. For some reason my h2 is not expanding to fill the width when I try and implement this, but your jsFiddle is solid.

Comment: @1ndivisible - Might be that you have other CSS that is interfering.

Comment: Yep. Just found it. Was floated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`, and then use CSS `calc` to get the right width for the middle `div`:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div><div id="two"></div><div id="three"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    min-width: 300px;
}
#one, #two, #three {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
}
#one {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 100px;
}
#two {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 300px);
}
#three {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 200px;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QXG7M/1/)**

You can then put the `h2` inside the the middle `div`, in this case `#two`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting `calc` but its support is limited

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar You are absolutely right. Unfortunately, I can't think of a fully-supported (particularly with earlier versions of IE) way of getting the same effect where the elements don't overlap (a case the OP has already considered and gotten working). I suppose using `table` may work, but that may introduce problems if the rows are not the same height.

Comment: Your opinion about my answer?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar I think your answer works. Probably better than mine, with (as you said) limited support for `calc`. w3d has already mentioned the possible issues with IE though. I think all of the answers mentioned are acceptable, but none are "perfect". I suppose it's really up to the situation.

Comment: This only works with a static width for the two divs. He said he wanted "varying width" for the two divs.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#parent {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
}

#parent div, #parent h2 {
    display: table-cell;  
}

#left, #right {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MAhmadZ/pMfLx/

Comment: IE7 and earlier have a problem with `display:table-cell` - if that is a concern.

Comment: Still considering IE7 and earlier? :-)

Comment: Occasionally, just depends on the target audience. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

try this out
i think it may solve your problem

```
<style type="text/css">
div{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid red;
position: static;
}

#one{
float: left;
width: 100px;
}

#three{
float: right;
width: 100px;
}
</style>

<div id="outerDiv" style="width: 500px;height: 500px;border: 1px solid red;">

    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var spaceLeft = document.getElementById("one").offsetWidth;

var spaceRight = document.getElementById("three").offsetWidth;

var totalSpace = document.getElementById("outerDiv").offsetWidth;

document.getElementById("two").style.width = totalSpace-(spaceLeft+spaceRight+4) + "px";
</script>
```

Comment: A bit overkill I think; you really shouldn't have to resort to JavaScript to solve this problem IMO.